# Prove that for each positive integer $n$, $R^n$ and $I^n$ are simply connected

Tags: general-topology

I'm currently trying to prove the following

Prove that for each positive integer $n$, $R^n$ and $I^n$ are simply connected. Here $I= [0,1]$.

Any hints on how to start as well as insight to carry through?

Thanks

Comment: Every contractible space is simply connected.

Comment: They're convex spaces, does that help?

Comment: The fundamental group of a product is the product of fundamental groups of the factors. Hence $\pi_1(X^n) = \pi_1(X)^n$.